# WIreless Problems in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

A few days ago I Moved to Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows 7. Ever since I moved to Ubuntu, my wireless connection at home does not connect although at university it works fine and I went to my friends' home and tried to connect to his wireless network...It connected without any problems.

I use a talktalk braodband at my home.

Can somebody help me connect to talktalk network wirelessly.

Comment: Does the wireless icon at the top of your screen show any available connections? Also can you show us the output of ifconfig?

Comment: Yes there is wireless icon available but it does not connect. Since im new on Ubuntu so dont know what you mean by "ifconfig"

Comment: Please open a terminal, type ``ifconfig`` and show us the output. Can you click the icon and tell me whether your wireless network is available there? If so, what happens when you click it and try to connect?

Comment: When I click on my network. I get an error after sometimes "Disconnected- you are not offline"

Comment: I see, so no real error message other than the "Disconnected"? Because the latter just means you are unable to connect. What you can try to do is go to "Edit Networks" and then edit your wireless network and see if you typed in your credentials correctly.

Comment: I have done this all but so far have not succeeded to connect to my network.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17660/discussion-between-mrhug-and-user158267).

Comment: As discussed in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17660/discussion-between-mrhug-and-user158267) you should post a screenshot of your working network-settings from windows

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the wireless option at the top right of your screen and select the Network you want to connect to, (in this example eduroam):

[image]

2. ensure that WLAN is enabled. This is done with a small hook next to "Enable WI-FI"

Comment: As he indicates in the comments this solution is not effective for him.